# Microsoft winsdkfb Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again. C# WinRT

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-runtime, windows-10, facebook-login

For our new Windows 10 application (C# + XAML) we are using the new https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb/ login, however since we have migrated to this login I am having no luck with facebook login.

We are using `FBResult result = await sess.LoginAsync(permissions);` and I am getting this error all the time: "Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again."

[image]

My code is litteraly a copy and paste from the samples they did on github:
I have checked my SID and FacebookAppId and they are the same on both the app and the Facebook website.

```
public async Task<string> LogIntoFacebook()
        {
            //getting application Id
            string SID = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();

            //// Get active session
            FBSession sess = FBSession.ActiveSession;
            sess.FBAppId = FacebookAppId;
            sess.WinAppId =  SID;

            //setting Permissions
            FBPermissions permissions = new FBPermissions(PermissionList);

            try
            {
                // Login to Facebook
                FBResult result = await sess.LoginAsync(permissions);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    // Login successful
                    return sess.AccessTokenData.AccessToken;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Login failed
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IErrorService>().ReportErrorInternalOnly(ex);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IErrorService>().ReportErrorInternalOnly(ex);
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

by doing this:

```
//getting application Id
string SID = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();
```

it is generating me an SID that looks like this:
ms-app://s-1-15-2-0000-bla-bla-bla-667/ 
so I tried adding ms-app:// to the facebook developer settings page but it did not want it, so I tried removing ms-app:// from the SID when passing it to `WinAppId` but still no luck

[image]

I have filled the field Windows Store SID wih My FBAppId :
[image]

does anyone have this issue?

Edit 1:
My code is copy and paste from here: http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/

Edit2: playing the samples from Microsoft my issues is coming from my Application Id.
I did follow step 6:
(Enable OAuth login)

- Select the created app on developers.facebook.com.
- Click “Settings” from the menu on the left.
- Click on the “Advanced” tab.
- Under the “OAuth Settings” section, enable “Client OAuth Login” and “Embedded browser OAuth Login”.
- Click on “Save Changes”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying everything and NOT wanting to use WebAuthentificationBroker I have found the solution.

Go on the Facebook Developer website: https://developers.facebook.com

Then:

Go to your app name -> Settings -> Advance:

Under: Valid OAuth redirect URIs
you need to add: https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

Save and you are good to go now!
[image]

Comment: i did all the above and still have the same error  !